# Linaro cross toolchain 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, arm, toolchain, linaro

I am developing a kernel on my PC (running Linux Mint 64 bit) and want to transfer that code later onto a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian 32 bit.
Now I am confused. Do I need my IDE to pick my **gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64** in the 64 bit version because I am developing on 64 bit or do I need it to pick the **gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian** because the target is a 32 bit Raspbian?

Comment: AFAIK, Linaro no longer distributes those Arm cross-compilers, you can now download them from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research myself, I can say that the toolchain/compiler needs to fit the address system of the development platform (in my case a 64 bit PC). Nevertheless, the kernel compiles for the 32 bit target platform (in my case a 32 bit Raspbian running Raspberry Pi)...